# ¿«Casi» siempre desencadena el presente?

Tags: tiempos-verbales, adverbios

Hace unos días tomé un examen en lo cual mis compañeros y yo tuvimos que llenar espacios en blanco de la forma apropiada del pretérito o del imperfecto del verbo proveído.

La última oración decía algo así:

> Cuando volvíamos, ¡un carro casi nos _______ (chocar)!

Vale mencionar que mi profesor no usa gramática correcta ya que no es hispanohablante.

Eso me resultó muy raro porque nunca he encontrado *casi* sin verbos en el presente (p. ej., «¡Casi me caigo!»).

1. En esa oración, ¿es apropiado utilizar *chocó*? (que, según mi profesor, es complemente correcto).
2. Si no, ¿*casi* siempre desencadena el presente?

Comment: Sí, no hay problema con el pretérito indefinido, de hecho, el pretérito imperfecto me sonaría raro en tu ejemplo. ¿Por qué piensas que el uso de *casi* obliga el presente?

Comment: @guifa Para decir la verdad el pretérito indefinido  me tiene más sentido que el presente (y el pretérito imperfecto claramente es la respuesta equivocada).  Solo es que ya he hecho esta pregunta a mi novia costarricense, quien insistió que el presente simplemente suena mejor y que ella siempre usaría el presente con *casi*.  ¡Gracias por contestar y compartir su conocimiento!

Comment: En el lenguaje informal y hablado, se oye lo que propone tu novia: "un carro casi nos choca."  Pero creo que tecnicamente "un carro casi nos chocó" sería correcto.  Es decir, cuando vayas al mercado, hazlo como dice tu novia, pero en el examen, pon "chocó."

Comment: Tendré que buscarla, pero había hace poco una pregunta sobre una oración parecida, y la respuesta mencionó que en el habla, es mucho más frecuente cambiar el anclaje temporal entre cláusula, cosa que se podría justificar, por ejemplo, al empezar una narración en el pasado y, al comenzar a actuarla, cambiar al presente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El presente no es obligatorio después de *casi*, pero para mi gusto suena mejor que si se usa un tiempo pasado:

> Cuando volvíamos, ¡un carro casi nos choca!
> Cuando volvíamos, ¡un carro casi nos chocó!

Ambas son correctas. Imagino que si una suena mejor que otra puede ser según la zona concreta del español de cada uno. A mí personalmente la primera me suena mejor. Esto es posible porque se usa el presente para indicar que algo sucedió en el presente de la acción narrada, aunque esta sea pasada. Pero no es obligatorio (ejemplos sacados del [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html), negritas mías):

> *En la catástrofe de diciembre de 1941, que **casi destruyó** la ciudad de Huaraz y otros puntos del departamento de Ancash, los vehículos con que negociaba Amado fueron arrastrados por las aguas, perdiéndose totalmente.*
>
> ---
>
> *Barallobre, sin embargo, no le hizo preguntas, ni **casi habló** hasta la llegada de la carta del Gobernador, que, como se dijo, era casi de noche.*
>
> ---
>
> *Una tarde, el hombre **casi destruyó** toda su obra, pero se arrepintió.*

E incluso:

> *Y aún pareció confirmarlo en esta sospecha el aire tranquilo, apacible, **casi diríase** aprobatorio con que el Dr. Pérez tomó noticia del hecho cuando él le llamó a su presencia para echárselo en cara.*
>
> ---
>
> *A la vista de los anteriores datos **casi habría que pensar** en una eficacia negativa.*

Comment: A mi también me suena mejor "choca" pero al leer ésta y la respuesta de @Diego me hacen dudar si estoy equivocado ya que parece que debería haber coincidencia en los tiempos. En todos los ejemplos en esta respuesta la hay.

Comment: @DGaleano los busqué así a propósito para ilustrar mi respuesta, pero también se encuentran con los tiempos cambiados.

Comment: Interesante. No es necesaria la concordancia de tiempos entonces.

Answer (score 4):

Para nada.

> La torre era tan alta que casi **tocaba** el cielo
>
> Él iba conduciendo tan deprisa que no vio el stop y casi **chocó** con otro coche
>
> Si pusieses esos imanes separados pero que casi se **tocasen** el uno al otro, verías cómo se atraen

Ahí van unos cuantos contraejemplos de que que "casi" no fuerza a usar el presente.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Creo que la clave es la concordancia: era->tocaba, iba->chocó, pusiesen->tocasen.